# Rounding a float to 2 decimal places in SQL

Tags: sql, casting, rounding

This is a column I calculated. The result looks like this: 8.434321

```
cast(tblCalc.property_size as float(10)) / cast((tblCalc.Total_WOs * 1000) as float(5)) as PER_1k_SQFT
```

How can I round this to 2 decimal places?

Comment: truncating means to remove digits *without* rounding.  In either case (assuming TSQL) use `ROUND()`

Comment: I tried Round(), but I must be erroring syntactically. How would that look?

Comment: It's probably easiest if you provide what you've tried and why it didn't work (error message, if the result was wrong then what was it, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

If this is T-SQL, I would use `round()`. You can do that by using:

```
round([value], 2)
```

This will round your output to two decimal places.

For your specific example, I substituted your own columns with static values of my own:

```
select round(cast(104053.542 as float(10)) / cast((22.543 * 1000) as float(5)), 2) as PER_1k_SQFT
```

This gives me 4.62 when rounded (4.61578 when *not* rounded).